# Docker Volume: Persist data for access across remote hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-volume

### Question

How do you access a volume across remote hosts so the data persists even if the instance goes down?

### My Setup

This was setup on a Digital Ocean droplet with -

- Create the docker machine from the cli
- `eval $(docker-machine env <name_of_machine>)`
- `docker-compose -f production.yml build`
- `docker-compose -f production.yml up`

### Docker-Compose file

My Postgres service is writing data to two different volumes - one for the database, and the other for backups.

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  production_postgres_data: {}
  production_postgres_data_backups: {}
  production_caddy: {}

services:

  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/django/Dockerfile
    image: mom_production_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.django
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: mom_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - production_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - production_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.production/.postgres
```

### Concern

These volumes are within that droplet, and my concern is that if anything happens to the droplet, the volumes will go with it.

So how do you create a volume that can persist and be shared across remote hosts or in this case droplets?

Comment: Native Docker has nothing built-in that provides this.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze, that is what I was thinking but couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add persistence block storage. For reference please refer the link below.
[add persistence volume support](https://medium.com/devsondevs/add-persistent-volume-support-using-digitalocean-block-storage-part-ii-9fea3eb958fe)